# How to disable a select option populated by database in javascript based on time range

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am working on a project in which values are fetched from the database in the select options. Now consider if the options consist of 5 options as   `aa,bb,cc,dd,ee`. Now my problem is that I want to disable options `aa` and `dd` (or such any other combination or even individual option) after the clock hits 11.30 am on Thursday and again enable it on 11.30 am on Sunday.

---

```
<form id="main-order-form"  name="order-form" method="post" action="" role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="offercode" style="color:#fff">
              OFFER CODE:</label>
              <select id="offercode"  name="choose_code" 
              class="form-control" tabindex="1" style="width:100%" required>
              <option value="">CHOOSE ONE:</option>
              <?php
                $query = "SELECT ID,CODE FROM offercode";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                  $code_id = $rows['ID'];                                   
                  $code_name = $rows['CODE'];
                  echo"<option value='$code_id'>$code_name</option>";
                }
              ?>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="foodtype" style="color:#fff">
              VEG / NON-VEG :</label>
              <select id="foodtype" name="foodtype" class="form-
              control" tabindex="2" style="width:100%" required>
              <option value="" selected="">CHOOSE ONE:
              </option>
              <option value="Veg">Veg</option>
              <option value="Non-Veg">Non-Veg</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="quantity" style="color:#fff">
              QUANTITY :</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" 
                  disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quantity">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                </button>
              </span>
              <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" 
              tabindex="3" value="1" min="1" max="20" >
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-
                type="plus" data-field="quantity">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> 
    <label for="submit-order" style="color:#fff">
      SUBMIT YOUR ORDER :</label>
      <input type="submit" name="submit-order" 
      style="background-color:#C70039;color:#000" id="" tabindex="4" class="form-
      control btn btn-login" value="SUBMIT">     
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function timer () {
    time = new Date();

    var hh = time.getHours();
    var mm = time.getMinutes();
    var dd = time.getDay();

    if (hh > "11" && mm == "30" && dd == "0,1,2,3,4") {
      // disable "offercode" select options (not all only the specified 
      // option) from Sunday 11.30 am to Thursday 11.30 am
    } else {
      // else keep it enable
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Use 'disabled' like it is in example: <select>
  <option value="aa" disabled>aa</option>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="dd" disabled>dd</option>
</select>

Comment: I am fetching the options from my database and not hard coding it.. I want to disable options after they are fetched from database

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom data- attribute to identify the relevant option elements  (e.g. querySelector) and set the disabled attribute for each option.

```
element.disabled=true;
```

**EDIT:**

to disable only specified offercodes here is one approach:

```
var select = document.getElementById('offercode');
var arrayOfCodesToDisable = ['aa', 'bb'];
disableOptions(select, arrayOfCodesToDisable)

function disableOptions(select, arrayOfCodesToDisable) {
    for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
      if (arrayOfCodesToDisable.indexOf(select.options[i].text) > -1) {
          select.options[i].disabled = true;
      }
    }
}
```

in the array "arrayOfCodesToDisable" just define the relevant offercodes. all options of your selectbox will be checked for the innerHTML (text) and will be disabled if they contain a text of the array.

Comment: Can you help me with the codes.. Or show me an example

Comment: @Shadow I added one approach to disable specific options.

Comment: sorry, had a mistake in the if block. corrected the answer.